# Not able to do rendering delay in css-grid-animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-grid

I am using [animate-css-grid](https://github.com/aholachek/animate-css-grid) and React library to build my portfolio in a grid design, I kind of achieved what I wanted here is the [pen link](https://codepen.io/hassan23/pen/moPQrx).
But when I click any of the boxes, the text which should go with the box rendered instantaneously. I want it to render after the box get scaled up.
this is piece code which I am using in rendering the text.

```
class Card extends React.Component {
state = { expanded: false };
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

render() {
    return (
        <div
            style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color }}
            class={`card card--${this.randomNumber} ${
                this.state.expanded ? "card--expanded" : ""
                }`}
            onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
            }}
        >{this.state.expanded ? <Text /> :
            (<div>

                {/* <div className="card__avatar" />
                <div className="card__title" /> */}
                <div className="card__description"> 
   {this.props.subject}</div>
            </div>)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am rendering the **Text** component at the time it gets the expanded state true.
I don't know how to delay it. The animate-css-grid library provides custom configuration but I am unable to understand how to use it. Can anybody who is familiar with CSS animations help me out here, please.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you've made any progress with this? Did my answer help you?

Comment: hey, I applied your answer, its helpful , just one problem with your solution is that if I had any animation in the text, I cant see it untill 500 ms delay is over, if you have any solution about that, it will be helpful, but animation is not my first priorty. so to sum it up, you solution worked, thankyou so much, and appologies for the delayed reply.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `className` around what `<Text />` returns and trigger an animation to reveal the text when the `--card-expanded` `className` is present. The delay of `500ms` feels good to me, but it's, of course, adjustable.

```css
.card-text {  
  opacity: 0;
}

.card--expanded .card-text {
  animation: 1s show-text forwards 500ms;
}

@keyframes show-text {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/zbqydW)